# counting unique identifier and stratifying

Tags: r

So I have a large dataset with 89 variables where multiple are unique identifiers attributing data in a relational DB. I want to see the frequency of unique identifiers as cross referenced by a second variable which is a factor?

i.e.
this does not work but is how I think would work -

```
length(unique(data$PID ~ data$ICD_grouping)
```

returning a table like

```
ICD_grouping        unique.PID
C43                   5
C47/C49               1
C50                   2
C56                   1
C57-C58               1
C80                   1
```

Sample data

```
 PID ICD_Grouping
1     1          C80
2   918          C43
3   919          C43
4   919          C43
5  1284             
6  1285             
7   550          C43
8   550          C43
9   550          C43
10  550          C50
11  920          C43
12  920          C43
13  921          C50
14  921          C56
15  921       C57-58
16  921       C57-58
17  549          C43
18  549          C43
19  922       C47/49
20  551          C43
```

Comment: To be honest, this post is a bit of a mess. I suggest you spend some time reviewing your post and then provide (1) a clear problem statement, and (2) consistent sample data and matching expected output. I also recommend reviewing how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We've been going back and forth here now for a while without any progress.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on your problem statement but provided I understood you correctly (unfortunately you don't provide sample data) we can use `table`. Here is a reproducible minimal example based on `mtcars`

```
table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb)
#
#    1 2 3 4 6 8
#  3 3 4 3 5 0 0
#  4 4 4 0 4 0 0
#  5 0 2 0 1 1 1
```

The output is an object of type `table` and shows the frequency for values for `mtcars$gear` (rows)  and `mtcars$carb` (columns). If you prefer a long `data.frame` we can do

```
as.data.frame(table(mtcars$gear, mtcars$carb))
#   Var1 Var2 Freq
#1     3    1    3
#2     4    1    4
#3     5    1    0
#4     3    2    4
#5     4    2    4
#6     5    2    2
#7     3    3    3
#8     4    3    0
#9     5    3    0
#10    3    4    5
#11    4    4    4
#12    5    4    1
#13    3    6    0
#14    4    6    0
#15    5    6    1
#16    3    8    0
#17    4    8    0
#18    5    8    1
```

Here `Var1` corresponds to values of `mtcars$gear` and `Var2` to values of `mtcars$carb`.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in the initial question. So the ID appear multiple times, so effectively all I want to know is how many unique IDs turn up with Var 2 in the dataset. Effectively asking a simple frequency table for a var2 but only for unique values of the ID

Comment: @SebWalpole Can you please provide sample data in a reproducible copy&paste-able format? For example, use `dput` and include the output. It might be useful (for future posts) to review how to provide a [minimal reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added a small example of the data. So I would like frequency of Var2 but of only unique identifiers from Var1. So 550 has multiple entries with C43 - should only count as 1 but also counts as a unique ID for C50

Comment: @SebWalpole I can't see any updated data in your post. Did you forget to edit?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work when I included it last night somehow.

Comment: @SebWalpole Ok I can see the data now but I struggle to relate the format of your data to your question. In your comments you mention columns `Var1` and `Var2`, your example code suggests columns `ID` and `varb`, and your actual data has columns `PID` and `ICD_Grouping`. So what's what here? Please use consistent variable/column names.

Comment: I was trying to use generic variable titles so it would be reproducible for any dataset but I wasn't clear enough in my question. Will amend @MauritsEvers

Comment: @SebWalpole I'm sorry but I don't think I understand your issue; at first I thought you might be after something like this `aggregate(PID ~ ICD_Grouping, data = df, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))`; but this doesn't match your expected output at all. In fact, I don't understand your expected output. Why do you only keep `C34`, `C50`, `C80`, `C56`? What about the other unique `ICD_grouping`s, like `C47/49`, `C57-58`; there also seems to be an empty `ICD_grouping`. Furthermore, how can you have 25 `unique.PID`s for `C50` if your sample data only has 20 rows? I'm very confused.

Comment: @MauritsEvers All my edits didn't come through. Check the output table again.

Comment: @SebWalpole Still not clear nor reproducible; I see 6 (not 5) unique `PID`s for `C43`.